# Debian jessie: how do I close openly accessible mDNS services?

Tags: debian-jessie, mdns

I received a report that inform me that the mDNS services are openly accessible on a server of mine.

I searched the internet, but I wasn't able to find how to close them in debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it using:
`sudo apt-get purge avahi-daemon avahi-discover libnss-mdns`

Comment: isn't there a way to achieve it without uninstalling those packages? I have another server where they are installed and mDNS service aren't openly accessible

Comment: Of course, you can simply disable it: `sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon`